# Bind an even to dynamically appended html in ionic 3

Tags: html, angular, ionic3

```html
I am developing an app with the help of ionic 3 
in the application i am generating dynamic html from .ts file and appending in HTML  . Now i want to bind and click event to html 

After user done an click event i want to refresh the content present in the dynamically generated html
please help to solve this 


    enter code here
my .ts file
with the below code i am generating html and appending to html
 outputHtml = '<div id="rpl_crt"><div class="sys_ot"><h6 class="itm_nme">My Cart</h6>';
      var innerHTML = '';
      let amount = 0;
      let savings = 0;
      for (let dt in data) {
        amount += data[cart].vv.value;
        savings += data[cart].aa.value;
        innerHTML += '<div class="cartlist">'
        innerHTML += '<div class="row ">'
        innerHTML +=  '<div col-3 class="itemimg">'
        let img_url=data[cart].product.images ? ConfigurationPage.commonURL+data[dt].aa.images[1].url:'assets/img/place_holder.png'
        innerHTML +=    '<img src="'+img_url+'" >'
        innerHTML +=  '</div>'
        innerHTML +=  '<div col-9>'
        innerHTML +=    '<h6>' + data[dt].aa.name + '</h6>'
        innerHTML +=    '</div>'
        innerHTML +=  '</div>'
        innerHTML +='<div class="btn_qnty row">'
        innerHTML +=  '<div col-5>'
        innerHTML +=  '<div class="row">'
        innerHTML +=    '<div col-3 click="abc(dt)"><span class="circle">-</span></div>'
        innerHTML +=    '<div text-center col-6 >'+data[dt].q+'</div>'
        innerHTML +=    '<div col-3 (click)="xyz(dt)"><span class="circle " >+</span></div>'///I want an click event here to do some action 
       // 
        innerHTML +=  '</div>'
        innerHTML +=  '</div>'
        innerHTML +=  '<div col-7>'
        innerHTML +=    '<div class="prd_dtl">'
        innerHTML +=      '<div class="proctprice">'
        if (data[dt].ss.value != 0) {
          innerHTML += '<span class="orgin_prc">' + this.currency.transform((parseFloat(data[dt].tp.value) + parseFloat(data[dt].ss.value)), 'INR') + '</span>'
        }

        innerHTML += '<span class="dsc_prc">' + this.currency.transform(data[dt].tp.value, 'INR') + '</span>'
        innerHTML +=    '</div>'
        if (data[cart].savings.value != 0) {
          innerHTML += '<p class="save_prc">' + this.currency.transform(data[dt].ss.value, 'INR') + '</p>'
        }
        innerHTML +=    '</div>'
        innerHTML +=  '</div>'
        // innerHTML += '<div class="quantity">' + data[dt].qt+ '</div>'
        innerHTML += '</div>'
        innerHTML += '</div>'
        let abc={
          code:data[dt].aa.code,
          data:data[dt]
        }
        clickEventMethod.push(abc);
      }
      this.totalAmount = amount;
      this.totalSaving = savings;
      // outputHtml += '</ion-list>';
      let footerHtml = '<div class="row cartfooter">'
      footerHtml += '<div col-4><p>Total amount</p>' + this.currency.transform(this.totalAmount, 'INR') + '</div>'
      footerHtml += '<div col-4><p>Total amount</p>' + this.currency.transform(this.totalSaving, 'INR') + '</div>'
      footerHtml += '<div col-4><p>Say <strong>Checkout</strong> to checkout all items</p></div>'
      console.log(clickEventMethod,'clickEventMethod')
      outputHtml += innerHTML + footerHtml + '</div></div>';
     
        this.appenData.nativeElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', outputHtml);//Appending the data at the end of the ion-content      // break;     
       
HTML
<ion-header [ngClass]="!isFromHome ? 'leftPaddingCssTitle':'cssTitle'">

  <ion-navbar color="danger">
    <ion-title>{{headerName}}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
    <div class="hint">
        <p>To go back , say <b>Go Back</b></p>
       <p>To Go cart , Say <b>Open Cart </b> or <b>Go to Cart</b></p>
          
       </div>
  <div class="main" #appenData id="main">

  </div>
<ion-content>
```

Comment: You can not get angular binding without proper component bootstrapping by angular. If you are using the framework you should use its in build features. Can you share what data powers you UI? You should use structural directives ngFor and ngIf here imho

Comment: its is a bot so i cant use directives